# How to import multiple properties into an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to import specific properties from lodash and export them under the same object.

Right now I am doing

```
import { omit, get, set } from 'lodash';

const _ = {
  omit,
  get,
  set
};

export default _;
```

As you can see, I need to repeat each and every property twice.

Is there some syntax that allows me to do it once? for example something like:

```
import { 
  omit, 
  get, 
  set } as _ from 'lodash';

export default _;
```

would be great! but this is obviously not supported at the moment.

Is there any other syntax that allows this?

Comment: Did you try `export { omit, get, set } from 'lodash';`?

Comment: No.. was not aware this is an option. can you please post this an answer so I can approve?

Comment: @HarunYilmaz this actually breaks my code - i need to change all my imports to accommodate to your suggestion. `import * as _ from .. ` any way around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export directly from a module as following:

```
export { omit, get, set } from 'lodash';
```

For further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: this would require to change related imports to be `import * as _ from ...`. any way around it?

Comment: I couldn't totally understand your intention. Can you please share how do you want to import these exported variables?

Comment: As a workaround to `import * as...` change, I did the following - I converted the file to folder with 2 files `lodash_breakdown` and `index`. in `lodash_breakdown` I do what you suggest. in `index` file I do the `import * as _ from './lodash_breakdown'` and export is  default `export default _;`.  This helped me avoid going over all existing imports.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could incorporate this in your answer.